# Show progress img while loading a page

Tags: asp.net

i want to show a loading gif while page loading. I am opening a popup window from javascript using window.open. I just want to display an image when mozilla or IE progress bar is being shown as gmail does when we login. Is there any way i can achieve this?

I know how to show loading img after page is loaded i want it with the progressbar of the browser

Comment: Did you read any of the related questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [show progress image while loading asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544944/show-progress-image-while-loading-asp-net-page)

Comment: no this question is totally different better read carefully

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a pre-loading progress bar script. Please see this links

http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-image-preloading-progress-bar

http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/image-preloader.php